# How to do a file/dir exists conditional in Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to write a function in puppet that will do a `fail` if the passed directory path does not exist.

`if File["/some/path"]` always returns true, and `if defined(File["/some/path"])` only returns true if the resource is defined in puppet, regardless of whether it actually exists.

Is there a way to do this with a simple `if` statement?

Thanks

Comment: Remember: manifests get compiled on the master. They know nothing about the client except for the facts it submits. So either write a fact that has this info, or take a step back and tell us what you're actually trying to solve so we can come up with a better approach than an if statement.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Workaround for this: use onlyif on an exec "test" and require it in your action you want to execute:

```
exec {"check_presence":
  command => '/bin/true',
  onlyif => '/usr/bin/test -e /path/must/be/available',
}

whatever {"foo...":
  .....
  require => Exec["check_presence"],
}
```

Comment: Oh that is evil, I like it :-)

Comment: Could be even simpler: exec{"test -e /path/must/be/available": }

Comment: Thanks. This works great for a single dir check.
However, I'm trying to validate an array of directories... If I add this to a function, I get a 'cannot redeclare' error.

Comment: Great idea, but this means that on every Puppet run there will be a "Exec[check_presence]/returns: executed successfully" notice, which is really annoying! Better would be:
exec { 'check_presence':
  command => '/bin/false',
  unless  => '/usr/bin/test -e /path/must/be/available',
}

This will do the same, but will only create a error/notice when the path really doesn't exists.

Comment: @ddario Put the unique name (e.g. path) in the name of the exec -- so something like ``exec {"check for ${thing}": ... }'' and then it will be unique for each item.

Comment: Anything which causes the "require" to fail will give an error as the whatever has a failed dependency, whether using onlyif or unless...  So technically it works but you'll get a lot of errors logged in your puppet logs...

Comment: this works very well for me, but, puppet agent always reports a change has occurred.
I have this:
<pre>

exec { 'mumble':

  path => [ 'foo','bar',],

}->

stuff { 'stuff':

}

</pre>

Comment: In my testing, **this doesn't work:** the "foo" resource is executed/applied even if the `/path/must/be/available` file does not exist.  Apparently `onlyif` not applying does not count as a failed dependency.  It does work with false and unless, though.

Answer (score 0):

I too was having difficulty figure out how to keep a module from running if a directory wasn't present.  This is what I found that worked for me.

```
exec { 'module_name':
   command => "command to run with variables", # Double quotes for Variable interpolation
   path   => "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:",
   onlyif => 'test -d /mydirectory',
   }
```

Adding the path is what really did the trick for me.  From some reason even if I added the path to the test command such as `/bin/test` it didn't seem to work right.

Hope this helps others who may be having the same issue.