# Check directory before creating file in puppet?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm trying to make a function which directory/file will be created only when the first directory exists, of not it must be skipped because of failed dependence.

I've tried [this "onlyif" workaround](https://serverfault.com/questions/516917/how-to-do-a-file-dir-exists-conditional-in-puppet), but unfortunately it doesn't work with my function.

```
$check_directory = file("/path/to/directory")
if($check_directory != '') {
    file{"/path/to/config":
        ensure  =>  directory,
        mode    =>  0755,
    }
    file{"/path/to/config/a.conf":
        ensure  =>  file,
        mode    =>  0755,
        content =>  template("config_template.conf"),
    }
}
```

I've got an error:

```
Error: Is a directory - /path/to/directory
```

Is there a way to do any other if statement? Or any parameter? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to simply use a `require` statement in your `a.conf` file resource:

```
file{"/path/to/directory":
    ensure  =>  directory,
    mode    =>  0755,
}

file{"/path/to/config":
    ensure  =>  directory,
    mode    =>  0755,
}
file{"/path/to/config/a.conf":
    ensure  =>  file,
    mode    =>  0755,
    content =>  template("config_template.conf"),
    require => File["/path/to/directory"],
}
```

This will make sure that the directory will be created before the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's difference directory. I would like to check another path to configuration, not the one that will be created. if I do so, I will get .. Error: Could not find dependency

Comment: Then you have to add a file resource for that new directory and then use `require` with that resource. See my edited answer.

Comment: Directory/file will be created only when the first directory exists, of not it must be skipped because of failed dependence.

Comment: Sorry, now I got it. But the sample code you wrote doesn't use the `onlyif` trick you linked to. So I am still confused - what exactly did you try and what didn't work. Please read [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) to avoid wasting your and our time.

Answer (score 2):

The ethos of @Sven's answer is absolutely correct: you set up resource dependencies in Puppet using `before`, `require`, `notify`, etc.  The only thing I would change is I would use the [`defined()`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#defined) function to test:

```
file { '/tmp/foo':
  ensure => 'directory',
  mode   => '0755',
}
if defined(File['/tmp/foo']) {
  notice("/tmp/foo is defined! making /tmp/bar/baz")

  file { '/tmp/bar':
    ensure => 'directory',
    mode   => '0755',
  }

  file { '/tmp/bar/baz':
    ensure  => 'present',
    mode    => '0755',
    require => File['/tmp/bar'],
  }
}
```

Two other useful tidbits:

- If you enable the ["Future Parser"](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/experiments_future.html) in Puppet 3.2+, you can access resource attributes like so: `$a = File['/tmp/foo']['ensure']`.  This would store the value of the `ensure` attribute for the `/tmp/foo` file resource in the variable `$a`.  If you decide to look into this, I would rewrite the above example to use `if defined(File['/tmp/foo']) and File['/tmp/foo']['ensure'] == 'directory'` (UNTESTED).
- If you're passing these items as parameters to a class, there is a sneaky way to access the values of class parameters via [in-puppet-how-can-i-access-a-variable-attribute-inside-a-defined-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013084/in-puppet-how-can-i-access-a-variable-attribute-inside-a-defined-type).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The below works if you're using `puppet apply` but *not* otherwise, because the `find_file` function is evaluated during *catalog compilation.*  That means this approach checks the existence of `/path/to/directory/.` on whatever server is used to compile the catalog, NOT on the host where the catalog is actually applied.  So likely not what the average user is looking for.  In a traditional puppetmaster/client architecture, the catalog is not compiled on the host that is to use that catalog.

---

Seems to work fine with `find_file`; hat tip to [this blog post](https://pillpall.github.io/puppet/2019/10/10/How-to-check-if-a-file-path-exists-with-puppet.html) that led me in the right direction.

```
$check_directory = find_file("/path/to/directory/.")
if $check_directory {
    file{"/path/to/config":
        ensure  =>  directory,
        mode    =>  0755,
    }
    file{"/path/to/config/a.conf":
        ensure  =>  file,
        mode    =>  0755,
        content =>  template("config_template.conf"),
    }
}
```

`$check_directory` will be `undef` if the directory isn't present, so that evaluates to false.

Note the addition of the trailing `/.` which causes the check to fail (and the code not to be run) in the case that `/path/to/directory` exists but is a FILE rather than a directory.