# Exists dir on puppet

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I want to check "if dir exists" condition with puppet how it done here [How to do a file/dir exists conditional in Puppet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/516917/how-to-do-a-file-dir-exists-conditional-in-puppet) but then if i write

```
  exec { 'check_presence':
    command => "true",
    path    =>  ["/usr/bin","/usr/sbin", "/bin"],
    onlyif  => "test -d /test"
  }
  file { '/test/123':
    ensure  => directory,
    mode    => '0644',
    require => Exec['check_presence']
  }
```

from `exec` i get alwyas `true`, and puppet always try to create /test/123

```
Debug: Exec[check_presence](provider=posix): Executing check 'test -e /test'
Debug: Executing 'test -e /test'

Error: Cannot create /test/123; parent directory /test does not exist
Error: /Stage[main]/tst::test/File[/test]/ensure: change from absent to directory failed: Cannot create /test/123; parent directory /test does not exist
```

Why he do it?! And how i must check parent directory exists?!

My puppet is 3.8

**UPD** I don't want to create `/test` ! I want to create `/test/123` **ONLY** if /test already exists!

Comment: The question you link to actually does have an answer that works - it's [the one by Mike Taylor](https://serverfault.com/a/851172/120438).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a file/dir exists conditional in Puppet?](https://serverfault.com/questions/516917/how-to-do-a-file-dir-exists-conditional-in-puppet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puppet doesn't have one native function for this, the only workaround:

`mkdir -p your_module_path/lib/puppet/parser/functions/` now you need to create this file `directory_exists.rb` with this code:

```
require 'puppet'

module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:directory_exists, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    if File.directory?(args[0])
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your puppet code, you can use the function:

```
if directory_exists('/test') {
  file { '/test/123':
    ensure  => directory,
    mode    => '0644',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please, where's i can find my_module_path? :)

Comment: that was an example, We have a module called profile and the path in my puppet server is "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/profiles/lib/puppet/parser/functions/directory_exists.rb"

Comment: Thanx you too! But in my case, i must return boolean (true/false) from func, or initialize var `$var = directory_exists('/test')` and then compare it `if $var == 1 { ... }`

Comment: @user423253 have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes, i accept this answer, thanx.

Comment: Functions run on the master, so this would only work if the code was being run in apply mode, not in agent mode

Comment: This works partially, If I use /foo/bar/tar it fails (although the directory exists) but if I use only /foo/bar then it works :(

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create /test itself I believe you'll have to do both things in an `exec`:

```
exec { '/usr/bin/install /test/123':
  onlyif  => "/usr/bin/test -d /test"
}
```

Using `install` rather than `mkdir` enables setting properties like mode in the same command.

---

The easiest way to create parent directories is to chain `file`s:

```
file { '/test':
  ensure  => directory,
  mode    => '0644',
} ->
file { '/test/123':
  ensure  => directory,
  mode    => '0644',
}
```

The semantics of your code simply requires the `exec` to "be instantiated" (that is, run) *before* the child directory is created. There is no optionality implied by this - `true` will run if `/test` exists, otherwise `true` does *not* run.

Comment: But i don't want to create /test ! I want create /test/123 _ONLY_ if /test already exists!

Comment: in this case, where i must set `owner, group, etc`?

Comment: Ok, it's work, many thanx you! But question is actual: Why puppet always return `true` in my case ?

Comment: @user423253 I missed owner in the resource definition, anyway, you can put what you want